# FBML and HTMLParser error

Tags: facebook, fbml, zope, zpt, serverfbml

The below code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
      xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>FB Test</title>  
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="FB.Connect.inviteConnectUsers();">Test</a>
    <fb:serverfbml style="width: 350px;">  
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:connect-form action="http://127.0.0.1/post_invite">     
            </fb:connect-form>
        </script>
    </fb:serverfbml>
</body>
</html>
```

Results in the following error:

```
   - Warning: Compilation failed
   - Warning: <class 'zope.tal.htmltalparser.NestingError'>: Open tags <html>, <body>, <fb:serverfbml>, <script> do not match close tag </fb:connect-form>, at line 16, column 4
PTRuntimeError: ['Compilation failed', u"<class 'zope.tal.htmltalparser.NestingError'>: Open tags <html>, <body>, <fb:serverfbml>, <script> do not match close tag </fb:connect-form>, at line 16, column 4"]
```

Yet the structure seems valid to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put tags inside of a `<script>` tag, and the strict ZPT parser is complaining about that. You'll have to somehow escape the contents, like with a tal:content="structure string:" construct:

```
<script type="text/fbml" tal:content="structure string:
    &lt;fb:connect-form action=&quot;http://127.0.0.1/post_invite&quot;&lt;         
    &gt;/fb:connect-form&lt;
"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script tag must not contain xml to my knowledge.

You could enclose the contents in xml comments and see if that works.